# Como hago funcionar Jquery en mi proyecto Ruby on Rails 6.0.0 y con Ruby version 2.7.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito ayuda, estoy tratando de hacer selects dependientes en Ruby on rails, pero la forma que conozco usa Jquery y no logro hacer que las funciones en Jquery me funcionen, instale el jquery con yarn, y modifique los archivos necesarios pero simplemente no funcionan, seguí varios tutoriales de la web y ninguno me funciona. Cualquier guía o ayuda lo agradecería mucho.

Primero que nada use :

yarn add jquery popper.js

luego Agregue el siguiente código en config/webpack/environment.js

```
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
    )
```

Requerir jquery en el archivo application.js.

require('jquery')

Eso fue todo lo que hice

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar (como código, no imagen por favor) los snippets donde realizaste las configuraciones para habilitar jQuery en tu proyecto?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Podrias pobar con estos cambios:

```js
environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
  })
);
```

Si eso funciona y recibes este error

> Uncaught ReferenceError, $ is not defined

Debes agregar lo siguiente en el archivo **app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
var jQuery = require('jquery')
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Con todo eso debiese andar bien.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero desafortunadamente no resolvió mi problema, sigue sin funcionar Jquery en mi proyecto.